# How to avoid Stack Overflow errors in infinitely recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, overflow, infinite

I know there are tons of posts about stack overflow errors and i understand why my specific one is happening, my question is basically how to move away from recursion in this specific case.  I have a class which establishes and maintains a client connection (for HL7 messaging specifically but it's essentially a glorified client connection) to another system which hosts corresponding server connections.  This class' constructor starts a new thread and runs the following method :

```
@Override
public void connect() 
{
    try
    {
        setStatus("Connecting");

        connection = context.newClient(intfc.getIp(), port, false);
        connected = true;
        setStatus("Connected");

        logEntryService.logInfo(LogEntry.CONNECTIVITY, "Successfully connected " + connectionType + " client connection to " 
                + intfc.getName() + "(" + intfc.getIp() + ") on port " + port);

        monitor();
    }
    catch (HL7Exception ex)
    {
        connected = false;
        setStatus("Disconnected");

        try
        {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(connectionRetryIntervalInSeconds);
            connect();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex2)
        {}
    }
}
```

Upon successfully connecting with the server, the monitor method simply checks, in yet another thread, if the connection is still up at a given interval.  If it goes down, the monitoring thread is interrupted and the connect() method is called again.

I did not anticipate this at first but you can quickly see why the connect() method is causing stack overflow errors after several days running.  I'm struggling to think of a way to get the same functionality to work without the connect method calling itself again every time the connection fails.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: move to iterativ approach instead of recursive

Comment: so basically a while(true) type approach that allows the connect() method to actually finish executing at some point and free it's resources?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd use a `Stack` object to emulate recursion when required.

However, in your case, why are you using recursion at all? A `while` loop fits the purpose.

```
while(true /**or some relevant condition**/){
   try{ //try to connect
      ....
   catch(HL7Exception ex){
      //sleep
   }
 }
```

I'm not sure of the purpose of your application, but there are may be better methods than sleeping. You could use a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), but if it's a single threaded program with one purpose it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: The app is used as a backend service for a webpage for a hospital admission system i'm building.  It is heavily multithreaded and manages dozens of such connections, as well as server connections.  Thankfully the code for server connections is much simpler and involves no such monitoring.  I will use your suggestion as a base but sadly it will require some re-thinking and re-designing of most of my HL7ClientConnection class, mostly surrounding the connection and monitoring logic.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Unless this is code is incomplete and `connect` is much more complicated than this, I don't see why you'd need any re-design. Where you're calling `connect()` now would just be the end of the `while` loop. The behavior would be absolutely identical. And perhaps don't use infinite recursion in the future. Especially if it's a void method with no parameters :-).

Answer (score 0):

When I had to deal with this issue in c# I used a Stack, and added new classes to it, instead of using recursion. Then a second loop would check to see if there were any objects in the stack that needed dealing with. That avoided stack overflow when I would have had huge amounts of recursion otherwise. Is there a similar Stack collection in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the `monitor()` method in the first place?  You mention that it is launched in a separate thread, then can't you just launch it in a new thread when the application comes up?  Then there won't be a recursive call.

Comment: Long story but basically in the HAPI API there is no interface that can be used to intercept in real-time when a client connection loses connection to the server, server connections do have such mechanisms thankfully.  I therefore had to get creative to make this "work" but i didn't consider recursion even though Netbeans did warn me!  The logic is basically : fire the connection attempt and, upon successfully connecting, launch the monitoring thread who then checks the status of the connection.  If the connection goes down, kill the monitoring thread and start over.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to an iterative approach as suggested, works beautifully!

```
@Override
public void initThread() 
{
    initConnectionEntity();
    mainThread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while (running)
            {
                if (!connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connect();
                    }
                    catch (HL7Exception ex)
                    {
                        connected = false;
                        setStatus("Disconnected");

                        try
                        {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(connectionRetryIntervalInSeconds);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ex2)
                        {}
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex2)
                {}
            }
        }
    };
    mainThread.setName(intfc.getName() + " " + connectionType + " Main Thread");
    mainThread.start();
}

@Override
public void connect() throws HL7Exception
{
    setStatus("Connecting");

    connection = context.newClient(intfc.getIp(), port, false);
    connected = true;
    setStatus("Connected");

    logEntryService.logInfo(LogEntry.CONNECTIVITY, "Successfully connected " + connectionType + " client connection to " 
            + intfc.getName() + "(" + intfc.getIp() + ") on port " + port);

    monitor();
}

private void monitor()
{
    monitoringThread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    if (!connection.isOpen())
                    {
                        if (connected == true)
                        {
                            logEntryService.logWarning(LogEntry.CONNECTIVITY, "Lost " + connectionType + " connection to " 
                                    + intfc.getName() + "(" + intfc.getIp() + ") on port " + port);
                        }

                        connected = false;
                        setStatus("Disconnected");

                        monitoringThread.interrupt();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connected = true;
                    }
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(connectionMonitorIntervalInSeconds);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                logEntryService.logDebug(LogEntry.CONNECTIVITY, "Monitoring thread for " + connectionType 
                        + " connection to " + intfc.getName() + " interrupted");                         
            }
        }
    };
    monitoringThread.setName(intfc.getName() + " " + connectionType + " Monitoring Thread");
    monitoringThread.start();
}
```